# AngularJS and MVC Framework, kind of projects?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, angularjs, angular-ui

I'm new into web dev, I'm making my first steps into this world, and I was wondering something, I saw on Wikipedia that Angular was for running "single-page applications"
Let's take a WAF like ASP .NET MVC where I can write some jQuery code for small things like dynamic data validation, some animations, and some other things that can jQuery plugin provide "easily", especially in asp .net mvc where there is a lot of helpers for jQuery.

Can Angular.js provide me those things too? Is it only useful for single page application, then ? Take for example, stackoverflow, is it too overkill to use it on a site like here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have some experience with ASP.NET MVC and single-page applications and I think they work well together, especially since MVC 4 and the introduction of WebAPI.

The goal of single-page applications is to improve the user experience by reducing loading times and by providing a more fluid navigation. Angular.js for example has not been designed to help you adding nice effects to your site or for DOM manupulation for that you have Jquery.

Angular.js will help you to handle navigation, client-side rendering, and if you have a lot of javascript code it will help you to manage dependencies and organize your code better, another good reason to use HTTP apis and client-side rendering is that you will separate the data and the presentation of the data, so you can test it and re-use it.

You can use jquery with angular.js and of course you can use Angular.js with MVC.

You can start taking a look to http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/overview/templates/breezeangular-template

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using ASP Web API, AngularJs, and Twitter Bootstrap for a couple of projects.
Tips:

- Learn and use ng-include and ng-hide for building the base GUI. It's easy and fast and uses the same way to animate.
- Use bootstrap for css (skip the JS-part). [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com)
- Use a third party library for animations. I used animate.css for css 3. Try to avoid JS-style animations if you can. Do a simple opacity animation when an element is shown and skip the hide animation. Then extend as you like after that. Animations usually break the layout somehow.
  [Angularjs + animate.css guide](http://www.divshot.com/blog/tips-and-tricks/angular-1-2-and-animate-css/)
- Use angulars forms validation. Google on guides if you need it. But don't forget the official documentation on AngularJs' web page.
- Skip directives until you must learn it, but don't be afraid to try it out when you do need it. The syntax is bad, but you only need a bit of code and then it is very easy to extend.
- Don't use id="foo" to hack in jQuery. Use (other people's) directives.

Good luck!